# Why is the address bar not showing in WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to show URL bar and webpage(below URL bar). But I don't know why it showing only web page.

**XML code:**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etURL"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:inputType="text"        
    />

<WebView  
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etURL"   
/>
```

**Java code**:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();

ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
ws.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
ws.setSupportZoom(true);
ws.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
ws.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
ws.setUseWideViewPort(true);
ws.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
ws.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

webView.loadUrl(mURL);
MyWebViewClient wvc = new MyWebViewClient();
webView.setWebViewClient(wvc);
wvc.setActivity(this);
wvc.setListener(this);
```

I think, address bar is covered by web page. How to display webpage below addresbar?

Comment: If I recall correctly is something webclient related. Try running the same without `webView.setWebViewClient(wvc);`

Comment: removed complete `wvc` part. but it's not running @blackbelt

Comment: what does *is not running* mean

Comment: Sorry I mean it is not showing URL bar @blackbelt

Comment: Are you sure you are not setting the WebViewClient everywhere else?

Comment: yes there is one class extended WebViewClient. And that class methodes are invoking @blackbelt.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.networkex.WebViewActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etURL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_below="@id/etURL"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This combination worked for me. Give it a try.